# Unable to view images on JAR

Tags: javafx

I have created a program that displays a few photos. I can view the photos when running the program within the IDE just fine. When I run the JAR the photos are not displaying.

This is an example of how I have added the photos into the code.

1.

```
  File file = new File("res/logo.png");
  Image icon = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
  primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
```

This displays the photo in the program when running through the IDE but not in the JAR

2.

```
URL icon = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("logo.png");
```

This doesn't show the logo at all.

3.

```
Image icon = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("res/nemours_logo.png").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
```

This displays the photo in the program when running through the IDE but not in the JAR

Here is a screenshot of my project structure.
project structure

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUKF0.png)

The res folder contains all images and is marked as a resources folder within intellji.The src folder is the source folder and contains classes.

Here is a screenshot of the Project Structure > Artifact section and the what the JAR includes.

[Artifacts Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teWjF.png)

I'm not entirely sure what else I could possibly be missing.

Comment: I recommend that if you're going to use Maven, then you should fully commit to using Maven. Maven's [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) has resources under `src/main/resources`. Use Maven to compile the project, not IntelliJ. Use Maven to execute the project in your development environment, not IntelliJ. Use Maven to create the JAR file, not IntelliJ. Note you can do all this _via_ IntelliJ by having IntelliJ execute the appropriate Maven phases and/or goals.

Comment: Alright I have made the necessary changes to the the images and media files I am using. Thank you for the help. I have on last issue. I am displaying a PDF file when users click on a certain button. The file is being initialized as such: File interPdfFile = new File(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("resources/file.pdf"))); However its not display not even giving an error. Does the getClass().getResource() not apple to files?

Comment: Resources are not files; do not try to reference them with `java.io.File`. If you need to read your PDF resource then open an `InputStream` to it via `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)` (or call `URL#openStream()` on the `URL` returned by `Class#getResource(String)`). If you need help determining the path to the resource, see the duplicate.

Comment: Your PDF file lookup issue resolution is the same as for other resources described in the duplicate.  Please re-read the duplicate and follow its recommendations and troubleshooting steps (plus Slaw's recommendations on stream handling).  Specifically -> resources, once packaged, are *not* instances of `java.io.File`, so don't treat them like that.   You should *not* include the `resources` prefix when getting a resource.  The correct way to turn a resource URL to a string is to call `toExternalForm` on it, etc.

Comment: Awesome, thank you both for your help!